# Simple inequality $\frac{4x+1}{2x-3}>2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$\frac{4x+1}{2x-3}>2$$

I have started with looking at positive/negative situations and there are 2 or that both expressions are positive or both are negative.

If both a positive we can solve for  $$\frac{4x+1}{2x-3}>2$$
 $${4x+1}>2(2x-3)$$

$${4x+1}>4x-6$$

$${0x}>-7$$

Or both are negative and then  $${4x+1}<2(2x-3)$$

And again $$0x<-7$$

So there is not answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake moving from
$$\frac{4x+1}{2x-3}>2$$
to
$$4x+1 > 2(2x-3).$$

The reason this is potentially wrong is that when you multiply both sides of an inequality by some number $c$, then the inequality flips if $c < 0$. In this case, it depends on whether $2x-3$ is positive or negative.

So, we should have
$$4x+1 > 2(2x-3),\quad \text{if }2x-3 > 0,\\
4x+1 < 2(2x-3),\quad \text{if }2x-3 < 0.$$

In the first case, we simplify (as you had done) to get $4x + 1 > 4x - 6$, so $0x > -7$. This is better written as
$$0 > -7,$$
which is always true. (This was a second mistake in your reasoning: you stopped at $0x > -7$ without making the right conclusion.) Keep in mind, however, that we are assuming for this first case that $2x-3 > 0$, i.e., $x > \frac32$.

In the second case, when $x < \frac32$, we similarly simplify to get
$$0 < -7,$$
which, of course, is never true. We therefore reject $x < \frac32$. In conclusion, the initial inequality holds for $x \in (\frac32,\infty)$.

Alternatively, as others have pointed out, you can move everything to one side of the equation first, then solve. This has the advantage of not having to deal with two cases.

Comment: Yes, but in both cases there is no answer

Comment: @gbox Not quite! I've edited my answer to show how to deal with the two cases. Your problem seems to have been that you didn't know how to deal with $0x$ (which is just $0$ no matter the value of $x$).

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**

Notice that
$$
\frac{4x+1}{2x-3}
 = \frac{4x-6}{2x-3} + \frac{7}{2x-3}
 = 2 + \frac{7}{2x-3}
$$
which is more than $2$ when the fraction is positive. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 5):

With these kind of inequalities I believe it is better to bring everything to left side and make everything into one fraction:
$$\frac{4x+1}{2x-3}-\frac{2(2x-3)}{2x-3}>0$$

Simplifying to: $\frac{7}{2x-3}>0$. Since the numerator is positive, focus on denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use equivalent but simpler inequalities
$$
\frac{4x+1}{2x-3}>2 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad
\frac{4x+1}{2x-3}-2>0 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad
\frac{7}{2x-3}>0
$$
Therefore we must have 
$$
2x-3>0 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x>{3\over2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

For $x > \frac{3}{2}$, we rearrange to $$4x+1 > 4x -6 \iff 1 > -6$$ and so it holds for all $x > \frac{3}{2}$.

If $x < \frac{3}{2}$, we rearrange to  $$4x+1 < 4x-6 \iff 1 < -6$$ and hence it does not hold for $x < \frac{3}{2}$.